# Display calendar format for date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

**Script for date**

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#ui-datepicker').datepicker();
 });
</script>
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <select class='form-control' name='route_to' id='member' onchange='selectPackage()'>
    <option value='packageSelect'>SELECT PACKAGE OPTION ....</option>
    <option value='manakamanaPackage'>Mana</option>
   </select>

   <div id="displayForm3">
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function selectPackage() {

    if (document.getElementById("member").value == "manakamanaPackage") {
        document.getElementById("displayForm3").innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='ui-datepicker' class='form-control' />";
    }

    }
</script>
```

**Explanation**

If we use type="date" in the input field then it works only in google chrome browsers.

That's why to display calendar for all browsers we defined the script with id='ui-datepicker' , it works fine if we use for input field which will be normal input tag *(**such as ::** < input type="date" />*.

But it does not work for input field which is displayed inside of javascript function *{selectPackage() as displayForm3}*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're appending the element after the DOM loads. You need to instantiate the datepicker library on the new element, right after you create it. Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select class="form-control" name="route_to" id="member">
        <option value="packageSelect">SELECT PACKAGE OPTION ....</option>
        <option value="manakamanaPackage">Mana</option>
    </select>

    <div id="displayForm3"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#member').change(function() {
            if (this.value == 'manakamanaPackage') {
                $('#displayForm3').html('<input type="text" id="ui-datepicker" class="form-control" />');
                $('#ui-datepicker').datepicker();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that I also amended your code to use an unobtrusive event handler as the `on*` event attributes are now considered outdated.